# microchip samc20n18.h SAMC20_DFP/1.1.151/samc20n/include/samc20n18a.h:212:34: error: redefinition of 'INT10_Handler'

Tags: c, linker, redefinition

1. Compile Error message :
   C:/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/Packs/atmel/SAMC20_DFP/1.1.151/samc20n/include/samc20n18a.h:212:34: error: redefinition of 'INT10_Handler'

samc20n18a.h has

```
void INT9_Handler                ( void );
#define SERCOM0_Handler          INT9_Handler
#define SERCOM6_Handler          INT9_Handler
void INT10_Handler               ( void );
#define SERCOM1_Handler          INT10_Handler
#define SERCOM7_Handler          INT10_Handler
void SERCOM2_Handler             ( void );
void SERCOM3_Handler             ( void );
```

because of SERCOM0 and SERCOM6 share same vector table, Atmel(Microchip) defines same INT9 interrupt vector. SERCOM2 and SERCOM3 also share same vector table.

Arm gcc compiler of microchip MPLAB tool chain insists  error: redefinition of 'INT10_Handler' and 'INT9_Handler'
How to resolve this error?

2. If I compile above project with XC32 compiler of microchip MPLAB tool chain,  XC32 compiler generates 'can not find _srelocate' without above redefinition error. I think _srelocate is not user definition but linker's definition.

I need at least to resolve one of above tow problems. please help me.

I have no idea. I just verified 'why vector is redefined' and '_srelocate is of linker'.

Comment: What does *your* code look like?  I think you are making some assumptions here.